# Add default Bearer token in Swagger Editor

Tags: swagger, openapi, swagger-editor

I want to specify the default value of a Bearer token for authentication in the Swagger Editor. Is it possible?

```yaml
securitySchemes:
   Bearer:
    type: apiKey
    name: Authorization
    in: header
    description: Enter your bearer token in the format **Bearer &lt;token>**
security:
  - Bearer: []
```

Comment: Do you use the online editor https://editor.swagger.io, or do you run the editor locally (e.g. using Docker)?

Comment: online one editor.swagger.io